# Accept multiple subsequent connections to socket

Tags: c, sockets

I have a listener that will pass arbitrary data, HTTP requests, to a network socket which is then delivered over TCP. This works fine for the first request but the listener does not accept subsequent new requests.

My question is:

If I have `sock=accept(listener,(struct addr *)&sin, &sinlen);` then, based on the socket function reference, the listener socket remains open and I should be able to re-call `accept()` any number of times for subsequent requests. Is this correct? If so, can someone more familiar than I with socket programming please explain how this code might look?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can `accept()` many times on the listening socket. To service multiple clients, you need to avoid blocking I/O -- i.e., you can't just read from the socket and block until data comes in. There are two approaches: you can service each client in its own thread (or its own process, by using `fork()` on UNIX systems), or you can use `select()`. The `select()` function is a way of checking whether data is available on any of a group of file descriptors. It's available on both UNIX and Windows.

Comment: You forgot one option, you can also fork which is the traditional Unix way of handling things.

Comment: If you use separate threads you don't need to avoid blocking I/O.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple example from [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#a-simple-stream-server).

```
while(1) {  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
        get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
        s, sizeof s);
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

    if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
        close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
        if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
        close(new_fd);
        exit(0);
    }
    close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
}
```

The child process — after the `fork()` — handles the communication asynchronously from `accept()`ing further connections in the parent.

Comment: A mere link is not an answer.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Yes, people naturally join witch hunts.

Comment: I've added in the most relevant section from that site; _that_ is how you make a link-only answer not be close-bait.

Comment: Thanks, Donal. That actually makes sense instead of down voting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have the right general idea.

While my C socket programming is a bit rusty, calling accept on a server socket sets up the communications channel back to the client side of the socket.  Calling accept on future connection attempts will set up multiple socket channels.

This means that one should take care to not overwrite a single shared structure with a specific connection's data, but it doesn't sound like that's the kind of error you would be prone to make.